# Connecting Lenovo Screen to HP Laptop

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, lenovo

I have an HP laptop dual booting Windows 10 (I think) and Ubuntu 20.04. I've been unsuccessfully trying to connect it to a Lenovo screen while on Ubuntu.

Furthermore, I can have it connected to my laptop as long as the screen is turned off, and my laptop already recognizes it. However, if I turn on the Lenovo screen, both screens go black and the Lenovo one keeps checking for signal, once in a while.

On the other hand, while on Windows, everything works out fine.

Do you know what the problem might be?

I'm sure I should be saying a lot more information that I don't know I should, so please let me know if it is useful to know anything else.